# Reentering the Schengen space with a single-entry long stay D national visa and permit of stay

Tags: visas

I'm studying in Italy I hold an Italian permit of stay. But my long-stay Italian national visa is for a single entry.

Can I leave and reenter freely in the Schengen space, for example to make a travel to Croatia, using the permit of stay?

My current information is that with the permit of stay I can travel freely outside and return to the Schengen space, but I'm wondering if it is not in contradiction with the number of entries in my visa.

Thanks.

Comment: `permit of stay` is **Permesso di soggiorno**?

Comment: yes, Permesso di soggiorno

Answer (score 2):

If you with 'permit to stay' mean a regular residence permit, the residence permit replaces your national visa. The residence permit allows you to freely enter and exit the Schengen area with no limit to the number of entries.